# Symfony2 mvc model explanation

Tags: symfony, model-view-controller, model, entity

I am getting confused over what `model` in `mvc` actually means. I know Symfony2 is not using a model in a traditional sense, but lets assume I wanted to use that terminology.

My problem is, I have more than one `enitity`. So if I wanted to use the term `model` would I be having different `models` (as there are more than one `entity`), or do all `entities` represent the (one) `model`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each letter of MVC is a layer in an application therefore the model layer holds all your entities. Model or entity classes are part of the model layer (class != layer).

I'd recommend [this blog from the creator of Symfony](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/49/what-is-symfony2). He talks about why Symfony isn't advertised as a MVC framework and instead prefer talking about how he cares more about the separation of concerns.